# How to pass 'HH:MM AM/PM' in date of localNotificationSchedule of push notification?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am creating a reminder app where the app takes time and day as input from the user, and at the given time and day app will give a local scheduled push notification to the user.
eg: time is in string format like '02:00 AM', '09:23 PM' .....
and day is in array like [1,4,7]. where 1 represents Monday, 4 represents Wednesday and so on.

so overall goal is to give notification to a user on given time (eg '05:56 PM') at a given days (eg. Monday, Tuesday Saturday )

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  message: "It's time to do some meditation :)", 
  date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), // in 60 secs
  allowWhileIdle: true, 

  
  repeatType: 'day',
  repeatTime: 2, 
});
```

Any idea how i can convert my string like '12:34 AM' to seconds, so i can pass the seconds inside `new Date(Date.now() + seconds)`

Comment: _"eg: time is in string format like '02:00 AM', '09:23 PM' ..... and day is in array like [1,4,7]"_ - Why don't you use a datetime picker that spits out a well-formated ISO date?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `momentjs`'s `diff` function in this way:

```js
console.log(moment('12:34 AM', 'HH:mm: A').diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```